# Websockets in python Quart with multiple workers?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, redis, quart, hypercorn

#### Websockets in python Quart with multiple workers?

Is there a solution to broadcast a message when my app is launched across multiple workers - for example using hypercorn?

I'm currently launching my app like this:

```sh
$ hypercorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 -w 4 wsgi:app
```

But the documented solution is to keep the connected clients in memory, with no way to broadcast to others that subscribed to the same event.

Any ideas? I was thinking to use Redis to achieve this, but I would like a simpler solution.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes, I solved it. I'm using Redis and PUB/SUB to send messages. Every time a user creates a WebSocket, I'm subscribing to which events the user is expecting. Then, when another process publishes a message that another process is subscribed to, it will receive it and send it to the FE.
Some key words:
__asyncio.Queue()__,
__redis PUB/SUB__,
__Quart web sockets__

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a simpler solution than Redis (or similar third party tool) for this.

It is possible to run Hypercorn with memory shared across the workers, but it isn't simple to setup. [Start here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) if you want to try this. At some point though you may have workers across multiple machines, in which case shared memory no longer works.

Comment: Thanks @pgjones for your answer. I will take a look and try with memory shared.